# cursor moves one space to the left redux form react native

Tags: react-native, redux-form

So I am having a problem with redux form and the cursor moving one position to the left when typing from the middle of the word. What can I do to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Facing the same issue. Were you able to find any workaround?

Comment: I have the same problem. Should we create a support item on react native github? I think this bug only exist in Android.

Comment: It seems to be fixed when you use an useState in the component. You can set the starting value and the update the state property on onChangeText. I could only reproduce this on Android.